# Passport expiration

Tags: usa, international-travel

I have my immigrant interview in October, but my passport expires in 7 months, in April 2018.

Can I still go ahead and use my old passport for the visa, once issued? And can I get a new one to attach to the old one?

I won't be traveling until January next year.

Comment: Sorry but I can't work out what you're asking. What kind of visa are you applying for? In case it makes a difference, what is your nationality?

Comment: If it is an immigrant visa you are getting the passport only need be valid when you enter, while the visa itself is single entry and has no value at all once you've used it and gotten the green card (it should arrive within a couple of months after you enter), so there's no need for a new visa when you renew the passport.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your response. I'm a Ghanaian looking to soon migrate to the USA with an immigrant visa. My interview is in October. Whiles my current passport expires in April. So about 7 months. My issue is I will travel to the USA next January but then I will have less than 6 months for it to expire. Will I have issues with Usa immigration whiles entering

Answer (score 1):

According to [8 CFR 211.2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.2) and [22 CFR 42.64](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/42.64)(b), the passport must be valid for at least 60 days after the expiration of the immigrant visa, unless you are the spouse, unmarried son or daughter, or parent of a US citizen (in which case you are not required to have a passport). According to [9 FAM 504.10-2(A)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM050410.html#M504_10_2_A)(1), your immigrant visa validity (which is usually 6 months) may be limited to less than 6 months to make sure it expires 60 days before the passport expiration. In your case, that means your immigrant visa may be set to expire in February 2018; since you will be entering the US in January 2018, that should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. In this case, do I inform the embassy or they will do so once they see that my passport expires in April 2018. I'm going on an F2A. My husband is a LPR